# avoiding from rows overlapping inside a panel in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter `bootstrap 3.3.6` and I have designed a panel which contains some rows as follows(`a part of my code`), however the rows put out side of the panel. 
Is it possible to put rows inside the panel without defining column grids?

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center">
            دستورات کارت
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <h4>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="csn" class="label label-default control-label pull-right">
                            شماره سریال کارت
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="csn">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" id="submitCSN" class="btn btn-primary center-block">  <b>
                            دریافت شماره سریال کارت
                    </b></button>                     
                </h4>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            My Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Note that if I do not use row, then label overlap with input-text.

I have another problrm:

I am using farsi fonts (which is a right to left one), and I have defined a simple CSS which load an appropriate font from a directory as follow:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url("../myFonts/BNAZANIN.TTF");
}
h4{
    font-family:myFirstFont;
}
```

However, as you see in the above picture, the font did not change to `myFirstFont` in `<h4>` tag.

**Update:**

please see this example which provide from w3schools (`you could see overlapping`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. H4 tags, just like the other 'H' tags are used to define heading like titles. You should not use them to hold multiple div's, span's etc.
   This is probably the reason why it doesn't apply the font to your H4.

You could remove the label and div then it should work.

check out [w3 schools heading tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)

2. The class .row is used to remove the gutter from bootstrap. It does not do anything more than:

`margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;`

For this to work you should have a width specified. But it really doesn't make any sense to remove a gutter when not using the bootstrap grid.

Comment: yes, but it did not worked properly, Indeed I removed div and label and used span, however when I want to have two or more span, they overlap with each other. Even if I use <br> when I enlarge the font of span, it overlap with input text. My worst problem is overlapping in rows, How can I avoid it.

Comment: A made a fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16046/ Is it this you are trying to achieve? Else make a fiddle with the html elements for me and i will try to apply proper css for you.